# How to scrape website with infinte scrolling?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to crawl [this website](http://www.jabong.com/home-living/furniture/new-products/). I have written a spider but it is only crawling the front page, i.e. the top 52 items.

I have tried this code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
a=[]
from aqaq.items import aqaqItem
import os
import urlparse
import ast

    class aqaqspider(BaseSpider):
        name = "jabong"
        allowed_domains = ["jabong.com"]
        start_urls = [
            "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/",
        ]

        def parse(self, response):
            # ... Extract items in the page using extractors
                    n=3
                    ct=1

                    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
                    sites=hxs.select('//div[@id="page"]')
                    for site in sites:
                            name=site.select('//div[@id="content"]/div[@class="l-pageWrapper"]/div[@class="l-main"]/div[@class="box box-bgcolor"]/section[@class="box-bd pan mtm"]/ul[@id="productsCatalog"]/li/a/@href').extract()
                            print name
                            print ct
                            ct=ct+1
                            a.append(name)
                    req= Request (url="http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=" + str(n) ,
                    headers = {"Referer": "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/",
                            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)

                    return req # and your items
```

It is showing following output:

```
2013-10-31 09:22:42-0500 [jabong] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=3> (referer: http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/)
2013-10-31 09:22:42-0500 [jabong] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=3> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLASS)
2013-10-31 09:22:42-0500 [jabong] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-10-31 09:22:42-0500 [jabong] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

When I put `dont_filter=True` it will never stop.

Comment: did u got the solution?

Comment: No, i din't got any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `dont_filter` has to be used here since there is only `page` GET parameter changing in the XHR request to `http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=X` each time you scroll the page down to bottom.

Now you need to figure out how to stop crawling. This is actually simple - *just check when there is no products on the next page in the queue* and raise [`CloseSpider` exception](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider).

Here is a complete code example that works for me (stops at page number 234):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request


class Product(scrapy.Item):
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()


class aqaqspider(BaseSpider):
    name = "jabong"
    allowed_domains = ["jabong.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=1",
    ]
    page = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//li[@data-url]")

        if not products:
            raise CloseSpider("No more products!")

        for product in products:
            item = Product()
            item['brand'] = product.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'qa-brandName')]/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            item['title'] = product.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'qa-brandTitle')]/text()").extract()[0].strip()
            yield item

        self.page += 1
        yield Request(url="http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=%d" % self.page,
                      headers={"Referer": "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
                      callback=self.parse, 
                      dont_filter=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code, a slight variation from `alecxe`'s code,

If no products are there then simply `return` from the function and which ultimately leads to close the spider. Simple solution.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class aqaqItem(scrapy.Item):
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()


class aqaqspider(Spider):
    name = "jabong"
    allowed_domains = ["jabong.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=1"]
    page_index = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath("//li[@data-url]")
        if products:
            for product in products:
                brand = product.xpath(
                    ".//span[contains(@class, 'qa-brandName')]/text()").extract()
                brand = brand[0].strip() if brand else 'N/A'
                title = product.xpath(
                    ".//span[contains(@class, 'qa-brandTitle')]/text()").extract()
                title = title[0].strip() if title else 'N/A'
                item = aqaqItem()
                item['brand']=brand,
                item['title']=title
                yield item
        # here if no products are available , simply return, means exiting from
        # parse and ultimately stops the spider
        else:
            return

        self.page_index += 1
        if page_index:
            yield Request(url="http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=%s" % (self.page_index + 1),
                          callback=self.parse)
```

even though the spider yields more than 12.5k products it contains lots of duplicate entries , I have made an `ITEM_PIPELINE` which will **remove the duplicate entries** and insert into the mongodb.

**pipeline code** below,

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


class JabongPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = MongoClient().jabong.product

    def isunique(self, data):
        return self.db.find(data).count() == 0

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if self.isunique(dict(item)):
            self.db.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

and attaching the scrapy log status here

```
2015-04-19 10:00:58+0530 [jabong] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
       {'downloader/request_bytes': 426231,
        'downloader/request_count': 474,
        'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 474,
        'downloader/response_bytes': 3954822,
        'downloader/response_count': 474,
        'downloader/response_status_count/200': 235,
        'downloader/response_status_count/301': 237,
        'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
        'finish_reason': 'finished',
        'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 4, 30, 58, 710487),
        'item_scraped_count': 12100,
        'log_count/DEBUG': 12576,
        'log_count/INFO': 11,
        'request_depth_max': 234,
        'response_received_count': 235,
        'scheduler/dequeued': 474,
        'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 474,
        'scheduler/enqueued': 474,
        'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 474,
        'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 19, 4, 26, 17, 867079)}
2015-04-19 10:00:58+0530 [jabong] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: when i type this url http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/kurtas-suit-sets/kurtas-kurtis/?page=1 it becomes http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/kurtas-suit-sets/kurtas-kurtis/ so ur solution is not working  it is giving only 52 result and since the data is loaded through ajax i am not getting result more than 52

Comment: @Sameer Shaikh  Did you run the above code by changing the start url with yours??

Comment: ok it worked just i needed to send the headers in the request and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you open Developer console on that page, you would see that the page content is returned in a webrequest:

http://www.jabong.com/home-living/furniture/new-products/?page=1

This returns a HTML document with all the items in it. Therefore, I would just be incrementing the value of page and parsing that until the return HTML is equal the previously returned HTML.

Comment: but that link directly redirects you to the home page 
therefore unable to extract the page 
in that link i have tried crawling with that url also 
but it just shows the main page source 
so how to do that any ideas what i am doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Using `dont_filter` and making a new request every time will indeed run forever unless there's some error response.

Go through the infinite scrolling, in your browser, and see what is the response when it has no more pages. Then, in the spider, handle this case by not making a new request.

Answer (score -2):

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();    
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/womens-tops/?page=3');    
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0');    
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));    
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$htmldata = curl_exec($curl_handle);    
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Its working for me. Please call through PHP Curl

Comment: It does not belong here. The OP is asking about python+Scrapy specific solution.