# Scrapy crawl category links till product page

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

Hello i am trying to scrape a ecommerce website which loads data with scroll and load more button I followed this [How to scrape website with infinte scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709086/how-to-scrape-website-with-infinte-scrolling) link but when I tried the code it's closing the spider without an products may be the structure has changed and I would like some help to get me starting I am quite new to webscraping.

edit question 
ok i am scraping this website [link]http://www.jabong.com/women/ which has subcategories , i am trying to scrape all the subcategories products i tried above code but that didnt work for so after doing some research i created a code which works but doesnt satisfy my goal .so far i have tried this

```
` import scrapy
#from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

from scrapy.spiders import Spider
#from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from koovs.items import product
#from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector    

class propubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'koovs'
allowed_domains = ['jabong.com']
max_pages = 40

def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(self.max_pages):
         yield scrapy.Request('http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops/?page=%d' % i, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="catalog-product"]/section[2]'):
        item = product()
        item['price'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="price"]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['image'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="primary-image thumb loaded"]/img').extract()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('//*[@data-original-href]/@href').extract()
     `
```

the above code works for one category and also if i specify the number of pages, the above website has a lot of products for given category and i dont know in how many pages they reside , so i decided to use crawl spider to go through all the categories and product pages and fetch data but i am very new to scrapy any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: @Alecxe can you please help I followed your code but it's not working

Comment: It would be much easier to get help if you post the website that you want to scrape and also the code you have tried.

Comment: @stummjr i have added the code which i tried and also mentioned the website as suggested .

Comment: Are you able to solve the problem or you still need help ?

Comment: @Rahul yes I still need help i am patiently waiting for some one to answer

Comment: Nice. I'll give you hints. Try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: @Rahul ok please provide me with some code as I am very new to scrapy

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to understand is the DOM structure of websites often change. So a scraper written in the past will may or may not work for you now.

So the best approach while scraping a website is to find a hidden api or a hidden url which can only be seen when you anlayze the network traffic of a website. This not just provide you a reliable solution for scraping but also save bandwidth which is very important while doing Broad crawling as most of the time you don't need to download the whole page.

Let's take the example of the website you are crawling to get more clarity. When you visit this [page](http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops/) you can see the button which says `Show More Product`. Go to the developer tools of your browser and select the network analyzer. When you click on the button you will see the browser sending a GET request to this [link](http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops/?page=&page=1&limit=52&sortField=popularity&sortBy=desc). Check the response and you will see list of all the products in the first page. Now when you will analyze this link, you can see it has a parameter `page=1`. Change it to `page=2` and you will see the list of all products in the second page.

Now go ahead and write the spider. It will be something like:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from jabong.items import product

class aqaqspider(BaseSpider):
    name = "jabong"
    allowed_domains = ["jabong.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops/?page=1&limit=52&sortField=popularity&sortBy=desc",
]
    page = 1

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('//*[@id="catalog-product"]/section[2]/div')
        if not products:
            raise CloseSpider("No more products!")

        for p in products:
            item = product()
            item['price'] = p.xpath('a/div/div[2]/span[@class="standard-price"]/text()').extract()
            item['title'] = p.xpath('a/div/div[1]/text()').extract()
            if item['title']:
                yield item

        self.page += 1
        yield Request(url="http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops/?page=%d&limit=52&sortField=popularity&sortBy=desc" % self.page,
                  callback=self.parse, 
                  dont_filter=True)
```

**N.B.-**   This example is just for educational purpose. Please refer to the website's `Terms and Conditions/Privacy Policy/Robots.txt` before crawling/scraping/storing any data from the website.

Comment: that's exactly what I have done as you can see the edited question I have added the code i tried but the problem is it works only for category I want the spider to get products from  all categories. I used same request method to paginate and mentioning max 40 pages only crawls 40 pages where as for some categories the pages are more than 40 , can I create a crawler spider where I can mention these xhr requests in rules and crawl every category

Comment: And also I would like to point out the item need to extract information from product details page which are in this format http://m.jabong.com/vero-moda-White-Sequins-Blouse-1763164.html?pos=2 so how do I enter into these links from above code and extract info?

Comment: Yes you can create rules for crawling these pages.  You can also use alexce's example to crawl all the pages. Change the page number to page=500 and you will see the section with id `id="catalog-product"` is nowhere in the DOM. That's when you will know that there are no more products available. Then raise the Closespider method. Check the modified code.

Comment: If you want to crawl all the subcategories then get all the urls of the subcategory and then stuff all of them to the start_urls. This way you can get all the data from the subcategory too. You can either use linkextractor or callback a function that gives you all the links of categories.

Comment: Also there are different approaches to your problem of getting inside the link. One of them is to crawl all the urls of a subcategory and store it in a list. Iterate over that list and then callback a different method which will scrape the data from all those links as you've mentioned.

Comment: Can you guide me with a small example though I am a newbie I am trying very hard to achieve this . What I understand from my research and your answer is to scrape for links in subcategory pages and parse those for links to product info but I need a working example to understand better I getting better at theory but I don't know how to execute . Can you show an example for the same code  posted above it will be my answer to that question