# Download data from an online power BI dashboard

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, powerbi

I am pretty new to programming and kindly ask for your help.

I am currently analyzing travel restrictions imposed by countries during COVID outbreak. For the analysis I need to download a summary table from an online power bi dashboard, although it has no download option and no static URL. You could access the table in the 'travel restriction'-section of the [website](https://migration.iom.int/).

The data is being loaded after you scroll the page and one can't access the whole dataset untill one scrolls the page for quite a long time. I tried simple 'select all' (Ctrl+A combination) to copy at least parts of the dataset, but it doesn't work as well and helps to copy just one row.

Any ideas how to scrape the dataset? I would greatly appreciate any tips or solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scrape website with infinte scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709086/how-to-scrape-website-with-infinte-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

On this same page there is the DataSet:
[image]

Click on this and it brings you to excel download of data. Here you find the restriction data you are lookng for (at least this is wht I asume):

[image]